# Freeze multiple columns in excel using macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Under the Freeze panes, Excel currently offers *Freeze panes, Freeze first row* and *Freeze first column* options.
I was looking for an option where I can freeze the first *N*-columns.
I did a record macro to find out what Excel was doing when *Freeze first column* option was selected and it showed this:

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 1
        .SplitRow = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

But what actually is happening is a split column than the freeze pane function.

So when I changed the `.SplitColumn=4`, I ended having a split than freeze panes.

Is there a workaround for this or is this suppose to work only this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I can see your question is actually 2 parts.

1. Why does the macro choose Split instead of Pane and
2. How to work around it.

I don't know the answer to 1, so I'll focus on 2 only.

Since you want to unfreeze you need to use freeze!

```
Sub DoThis()

    Columns("E:E").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

Comment: To answer your question *why you use split if you want it to behave like freeze* - that's how the macro recorder records it... Thanks. It works. But my real question is not answered. How can I initiate a chat with you?

Comment: So the macro recorder does *SPLIT* window instead of `Columns("E:E").Select`... That's where everything goes wrong

Comment: Oh I see. Your question isn't  WHY the macro chooses to use split instead of Freeze?

Comment: Yes. But never mind. I was told that macro recorder is not the perfect *action-to-code* generating tool....